# How do people go about developing gigantic .css file?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

How do people go about developing gigantic .css file? Do they use some tools or they really code it line by line?

For example, here is one .css file that has 20K lines.

http://dkmstj1aljhw5.cloudfront.net/styles/dc3de668.app.css

Comment: It is likely that they are bundling multiple files together.

Comment: The file has been [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)), and is likely the merging of a few different stylesheets since it leads with [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Comment: This way too broad for SO. There are tons of frameworks that create large CSS files such as LESS and SASS. That being said, some people will do it manually. Also, as others have pointed out, often stylesheets get merged.

Answer (score 2):

The file you posted link to is probably generated from many smaller css files, and served as one big file, to reduce number of requests to server. Newer web frameworks usually provide some kind of a tool for managing assets.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is quite a broad question, but please see my answer below.

First of all typically very large CSS files can be part of a framework such as bootstrap for example.

On the other hand there are some CSS files that are long just by their nature. I have written a CSS file that has been 24000 lines before. This consisted of 8 separate files, all minimised into a single cached CSS file.

I hope this helps!